# Send multiple unique emails at one time

Tags: .net, smtp

I'm trying to find a .Net equivalent of the java code in this question:  [How to send multiple emails in one session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334753/how-to-send-multiple-emails-in-one-session) Amazingly, this question hasn't been answered yet on Stack Overflow (or I'm not searching with the right terms.)

I want to be able to connect to my SMTP server (this is a 3rd party server, not under my control) and send up to 500 emails or so at one time.  These emails are requested by our users, and are all unique.  I know I could loop through a list and send them sequentially, or even use threading to spawn multiple processes, but this seems to be wasteful.  I'd be opening a connection, sending one email, then closing the connection.

I've seen it implied that .Net will cache an SMTP connection, kind of like database connection pooling, but I can't find confirmation.  Plus I'd be relying on code that may have unintended side effects for the SMTP that I'm using.

Has anyone done this in .Net?  Did you use a 3rd party component?  Did you instead just manually implement the SMTP RFC?  I really don't want to have to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a SMTP object with

[SMTPClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx)

so create on of those and then call the `Send` method for each email you need to send.

You can't really send all those mails at 'once' but you can send them without recreating the SMTP object.

Comment: Yep, straight from the docs, it will pool until you `Dispose`: "The SmtpClient class implementation pools SMTP connections so that it can avoid the overhead of re-establishing a connection for every message to the same server"

Comment: Reading the docs?  Novel idea!  I can't believe I missed that.  Thanks for the answer and the comment, both of you.