# Senting bulk mails to recipient individually using Java Mail API

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I need to send dozens or hundreds of people the same message without having to display everyone's e-mail addresses.

Also I need tracking of respective action made to the each mail which i have sent (i.e., received status, open status, etc) 
Say i am sending message 1000 recipients in a fashion of 50 reciepient at one time.

While i am sending the email in BCC mode, i can achieve that the same message sent to dozen of people without having to display everyone's e-mail addresses.  But here i didn't able to track the respective action made to the each mail which i have sent.

while i amd sending the email in Normal mode, I can achive the both but it takes to long time to process all the 1000 recepients.

Is there is any better way to accomplish the both items which i need?
if so can you share with us to over come the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I answered your question on the [OTN Forum](https://community.oracle.com/message/13550547).  Here's my response:

> The only better way is to contract with a bulk mail service that will do all this for you.
>
> Whether you can do better may depend on what exactly you mean by "track the respective action made to the each mail".  If you want to know whether each recipient received the message or replied to the message, you need to send a different message to each recipient with some personally identifiable information.  If you only want to know whether the message was delivered to each recipient successfully, and you're willing to depend on Delivery Status Notifications (which not all mail servers support), you can determine from the returned Delivery Status Notification whether delivery was successful or not for each recipient.  But again, some servers won't return DSNs at all, and some won't return them in the standard format.

Also, I assume you've already tried using just a single connection to send a different copy of the message to each recipient, as described in the other answer.  If you haven't tried that, start there.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: [how-to-send-multiple-emails-in-one-session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334753/how-to-send-multiple-emails-in-one-session)

If today you're using one `Session` and static `Transport.send()` per Mail, this could speed things up a lot.